# Error [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(198)] after running json.decode(response.body)

Tags: flutter, dart

Repository:

```
class PlanosRepository {
  Future<List<PlanosModel>> load() async {
    final client = http.Client();

    try {
      final uri = Uri.parse('http://localhost:3001/sales/lista_planos');
      final response = await client.get(uri);

      if (response.hashCode == 200) {
```

Error after running this line

```
        final body = json.decode(response.body);
```

```
    List<PlanosModel> planos =
        body.map((json) => PlanosModel.fromJson(json)).toList();

    return planos;
  } else {
    throw Exception('Failed to load post');
  }
} finally {
  client.close();
}
```

}
}

Error:
[Image error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5QtP.png)

gives the error when I run json.decode, I've tried other methods but nothing worked

Answer (score 1):

Few points i noticed

1. Import http like this

```dart
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
```

2. When you make an API call you can directly use

```dart
http.get(uri);
```

Http client is for multiple request at the same time.

3. Not sure if the local host is running and you are getting it's data.
4. You can check

```
response.statusCode == 200
```

Instead of hasCode

Comment: Judging by the `else` flow of that `if (response.hashCode)` I would also suggest that you try using statusCode. `hashCode` usually refers to memory, not response statuses.